# How do I separately read arguments with %20 & + from URL using Flask in Python?

Tags: python, url, flask, url-parsing

I have the following URL:

```
https://ide50-username.cs50.io/search?q=New%20Haven+CT
```

When I use the Flask method:

`q = request.args.get("q")`

it simply returns me the string "New Haven CT", essentially converting both `%20` & `+` to a blank space

I want to read the arguments "New Haven" & "CT" from my URL separately as two items in a list. how do I do it?

Comment: %20 and + *do* both represent spaces in URLs; if that should be a literal character + it needs to be URL encoded.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to separate arguments with `+`. You can parse the URL by yourself.(Warning: it's not as safe as `urllib.parse.parse_qs`.)

`urllib.parse.unquote` function doesn't parse `+` to space, `urllib.parse.unquote_plus` does. [See the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote_plus).

An example:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote


def parse_query_string(query_string):
    pairs = [s2 for s1 in query_string.split('&') for s2 in s1.split(';')]
    parse_result = {}
    for pair in pairs:
        name_value = pair.split('=', 1)
        if len(name_value) != 2:
            continue
        if len(name_value[1]):
            name = unquote(name_value[0])
            _value = unquote(name_value[1])

            # separate value with +
            values = _value.split('+')
            if name in parse_result:
                parse_result[name].extend(values)
            else:
                parse_result[name] = values
    return parse_result


@app.route('/search')
def search():
    # Get raw query_string
    raw_query_string = request.query_string.decode()
    queries = parse_query_string(raw_query_string)
    q = queries.get('q')
    return ''
```

And there's a simple way, if you can make the url like `q=New%20Haven&q=CT`, Flask can parse `q` to multi values.

```
print(request.args)
# output: ImmutableMultiDict([('q', 'New Haven'), ('q', 'CT')])
```

Or parse it by yourself using `urllib.parse.parse_qs`.

```
raw_query_string = request.query_string.decode()
print(parse_qs(raw_query_string))
# output: {'q': ['New Haven', 'CT']}
```